# Running bitcoin node with already verified blockchain

Tags: bitcoin-core, verification, bitcoin.conf

I'm following this guide https://stadicus.github.io/RaspiBolt/ to setup a bitcoin full node on my new raspberry pi.

I already downloaded and verified the blockchain on my host machine. I also pruned it (6GB) so it can fit on my microSD card. I moved the `blocks` and `chainstate` folders to `~/.bitcoin` on my raspberry. But when I run the `bitcoind` service with the same [bitcoin.conf](https://stadicus.github.io/RaspiBolt/raspibolt_30_bitcoin.html#configuration) file proposed on the guide, the `verificationprogress` shows that it starts from 0.

I've tried with these options too:

`prune=6000`
`reindex=1`
`reindex-chainstate=1`

But none of them make the progress to be completed. I also tried waiting some minutes in order to see if the progress completes faster but that's not the case. What options do I need?

Answer (score 1):

I've found it. I've removed `testnet=1` and now it's fully verified. `reindex*` options are not necessary.

Huh, I had verified the blockchain from `main` net. I didn't know the `testnet` was using a separate blockchain?

Comment: Yes, testnet is an entirely separate system. Separate network, separate blockchain, separate currency, separate nodes.